# Getting Compile time error

Tags: java

I'm getting the following error :   cannot find symbol `color b=new color(Color.BLACK);`

EDIT: I'm trying to create an instance of the class color.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

    class eventqueue{
    public static void main(String args[]){


    final JFrame frame=new JFrame("PROGRAM");
    final JPanel panel=new JPanel();

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){

                final JButton black=new JButton("BLACK");
                panel.add(black);
                frame.add(panel);

                color b=new color(Color.BLACK);

                black.addActionListener(b);

                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setSize(400,400);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


            class color implements ActionListener{
                public Color c;
                public color(Color bc){
                    c=bc;
                    }
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    panel.setBackground(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Java is case-sensitive.

Comment: It should be `Color b=Color.BLACK;`

Comment: Oh this is horrible, it's not a case-sensitivity problem (as I previously thought); you have a class called `color` (lower-case class-names are a no-no already) in code that also uses `Color`.  That's guaranteed to confuse anybody that has to maintain your code.  You should strongly consider using a sensible class name.

Comment: :/ I'm still getting an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `color` is class that is locally declared in a `run()` method. Now that class must be declared before it's use.

Sample code:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ...

        // MOVE it HERE
        class color implements ActionListener {
            public Color c;

            public color(Color bc) {
                c = bc;
            }

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                panel.setBackground(c);
            }
        }

        // Now use it HERE
        color b = new color(Color.BLACK);
        black.addActionListener(b);
        ...
    }

});
```

---

Note: follow [Java Naming convention](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html).

Comment: but in my last program i defined it in the same way and it worked

Comment: That will definably not the same case. if yes then share the code.

Comment: It's compiling , but now im getting an error saying : `could not find or load main class`

Comment: You might to add `public static void main()` method, I just told you the part that is changed.

Comment: Yes its complete but im still getting the same error

Comment: I have defined the main method

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable as,

```
Color b = new Color(Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code

```
Color b = new Color(Color.BLACK);
```

to represent the Color class. Which is the thing you want in your code.

You can even see that there is a color (I really mean to say color) difference of both `Color` and `color`. Lowercase is the variable name and Uppercase is the Class name.

Comment: Indeed, but this should really just be a close-vote as "simple typographical error".

Comment: @OliCharlesworth already done!